# Solving for the functional shifts and its inverse

Tags: calculus, field-theory

I have two equations:

$$ f(x) = g(x+f(x))~~ {\rm and} ~~ g(x) = f(x - g(x)),  $$

where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are functions of a single variable. Given equations above what can one say about these functions? Which class of solutions do they belong to? How well do these expressions constrain the explicit functional forms of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

I obtained these equations by studying the simple translations of some scalar fields.
For example, if I have a field $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$, later of which I obtained by translating the former by some $f(x)$, as

$$ \psi(x) = \int dy~ \phi(y) \delta^D(x-y-f(y)),$$

where $\delta^D$ is the Dirac delta. By defining the $g(x)$ as an inverse translation,
i.e.

$$ \phi(x) = \int dy~ \psi(y) \delta^D(x-y+g(y)),$$

and so I get the above equations for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ as the requirement of the existence of the inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}$Write

- $\phi(z) = z + f(z)$, so that $f(z) = \phi(z) - z$, and
- $\gamma(z) = z - g(z)$, so that $g(z) = z - \gamma(z)$.

Then $f(x) = g(x+f(x))$ becomes
$$
\phi(x) - x = g(\phi(x)) = \phi(x) - \gamma(\phi(x)),
\quad
\text{that is,}
\quad
\gamma(\phi(x)) = x.
$$
Similarly $g(x) = f(x - g(x))$ becomes
$$
x - \gamma(x) = f(\gamma(x)) = \phi(\gamma(x)) - \gamma(x),
\quad
\text{that is,}
\quad
\phi(\gamma(x)) = x.
$$
So it seems $\phi$ and $\gamma$ have to be functional inverses of each other. And conversely, once you have such a pair $\phi, \gamma$ of functional inverses, $f(x) = \phi(x) - x$ and $g(x) = x - \gamma(x)$ will satisfy your functional equations.